# failed to open stream error message while trying to include phpseclib

Tags: include-path, php, phpseclib

I'm trying to follow the instructions for installing phpseclib.

I unpackaged everything and created a new `phpseclib` folder into `/usr/share/pear`.  So I have the following stucture:

```
/usr/share/pear/phpseclib/
                          Net
                          Crypt
                          File
                          Math
```

I determined the `/usr/share/pear` path by checking the [`get_include_path` method](http://php.net/get_include_path).

And now i'm trying to create a page that uses the phpsec library.

Here's the php page I'm playing with:

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
```

The page bombs with an error message that says;

> warning:  include(Net/SSH2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test/sshtest.php on line 4.
>   Warning include(): failed opening 'Net/SSH2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:phpseclib') in /var/www/test/sshtest.php on line 4.

`/var/www/test` the webfolder where my page is. Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code to read:

```
<?php 

set_include_path(get_include_path() . get_include_path().'/phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
echo('if you are reading this, phpseclib has been included');
```

and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did not you forget to place a slash / after setting the path?

So, should be like:

```
 <?php
          set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib/');
          include('Net/SSH2.php');
      ?>
```

or

```
<?php
              set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib' . PATH_SEPARATOR);
              include('Net/SSH2.php');
          ?>
```

Comment: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ has the install instructions... you'll see the exact same code i have on this page...

Comment: Alright. Just try roughly set the absolute path. For example create folder "phpseclib" in your folder "test" and do  <?php set_include_path("C:var/www/test/phpseclib") ; ?> dont forget to put all needed files inside it.

Comment: I changed the code to read: 

             <?php 
                   set_include_path(get_include_path() . get_include_path().'/phpseclib');
                   include('Net/SSH2.php');
                   echo('if you are reading this, phpseclib has been included');
             ?>

And now the page works.