# How to install phpseclib?

Tags: php, installation, phpseclib

I have installed Apache on my machine so I can use localhost as a PHP server. That works. Right now I am trying to use PHP to send files via SFTP to another server. I looked around a bit and saw phpseclib was recommended. I can't seem to figure out how to install phpseclib. Here are the lines that the website gave:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SFTP.php');
```

> You have to set the include path.

I understand what these words mean but I have been unable to get it working. I am using a mac. My server is in `/Users/diego/Sites/`.  Where exactly do I need to put the `phpseclib` folder? What lines do I need to put in my php file so that `phpseclib` is included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by installing PEAR, following [this guide.](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)

By following the guide above, I figured out that apache2 was looking for `php.ini` in my `/etc/` folder. But I ran into a problem. In my `/etc/` folder there was no `php.ini` file. But there was `php.ini.defualt`. So I 'saved as' `php.ini.default` to `php.ini` and then modified the include_path.

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
include_path = ".:/Users/diego/pear/share/pear:/php/includes"
```

PHP is no longer throwing an error saying that `phpseclib` cannot be found.

Answer (score 9):

I tried installing phpseclib on linux machine. It worked perfectly for me. I hope you need a similar configuration on your Mac.

On linux server execute following command.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql php-pear
sudo pear channel-discover phpseclib.sourceforge.net
sudo pear remote-list -c phpseclib
sudo pear install phpseclib/Net_SSH2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On Mac, using mac port execute following command
    sudo port -v selfupdate
    sudo port install php54-ssh2

```
#add this to the php.ini file /etc/php.ini, it can be placed at the end of the file
extension=/opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ssh2.so
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

On Mac, using homebrew execute following command.
    brew install php54-ssh2

Download phpseclib library and include into your project directory.

In the relevant php file add following code.

```
include('phpseclib1.0.5/Net/SFTP.php');

set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'phpseclib');
define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('555.55.55.55', 22);

if(!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
    die('Login failed!');
} else {
    echo $sftp->pwd();
    echo $upload = $sftp->put('/sftp/'.$filename, $uploadedfile, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');` will add phpseclib as a relative path. So doing `include('Net/SFTP.php')` will include `phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php` but that's relative to whatever your working directory is.

PEAR often has an absolute path in the include_path. So that's something you could try doing. Putting phpseclib in some directory (prob outside of the document root) and then putting that directory into your include_path.

Note that this matters more if you downloaded phpseclib from sourceforge.net or if you're on the 1.0 branch.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Diego, for the hint to install PEAR. I got it working with the following steps:

First, install [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php).

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

If the **wget** command doesn't work, please install that package, to get it working.

```
$ sudo apt-get install wget
```

After successfully installing PEAR, configure it with this [guide](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.cli.modifyingphpini).

The `php.ini` file, can be found in `/etc/php5/apache2`. You have to modify this file.

Suddenly, I tested the new libary. But I got a bunch of error's instead, like in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762655/phpseclib-gives-me-a-strange-erros) described.
For that issue, I got the solution for it, in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619528/failed-to-open-stream-error-message-while-trying-to-include-phpseclib).