# phpseclib gives me a strange erros

Tags: php, phpseclib

Im trying to use this, but it just gives me this errors and i have no clue how to fix that..

> Warning: include_once(Math/BigInteger.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 891
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Math/BigInteger.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 891
>
> Warning: include_once(Crypt/Random.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 895
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Crypt/Random.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 895
>
> Warning: include_once(Crypt/Hash.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 899
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Crypt/Hash.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 899
>
> Warning: include_once(Crypt/Base.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 904
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Crypt/Base.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 904
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   phpseclib_resolve_include_path() in
>   /home/www/sfs_web/statistics/_public/_functions/Server/Net/SSH2.php on
>   line 1226

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('host');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
  echo('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->exec('the cmd line...");
$ssh->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

phpseclib is probably not in your include_path. Quoting [phpseclib.sourceforge.net](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net),

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

include('Net/SSH2.php');
?>
```

You'll need to adjust that as appropriate. If phpseclib is in the vendor/phpseclib directory then do `'vendor/phpseclib'` instead, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need set_include_path.
And, in my way I've  replace  in *ssh2.php* all include directive

```
include_once(Math/BigInteger.php)
```

on

```
stream_resolve_include_path(Math/*****.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

For CodeIgniter <=3,

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH.'libraries/phpseclib');